# RuntimeError: expected scalar type Double but found Float for optimization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, pytorch

I used the following code to optimize the proposed dataset:

```
import yfinance as yf
import torch
import random # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import json
import numpy as np
#from deap import base, creator, tools, algorithms

from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td
#from datetime import datetime
import simulated_bifurcation as sb


asset_name = 'AAPL'

import numpy as np

def generate_weights(data):
    # Get the number of columns in the data
    num_cols = data.shape[1]

    # Generate random weights between 0 and 1
    weights = np.random.rand(num_cols, num_cols)

    # Normalize the weights
    normalized_weights = weights / np.sum(weights)

    return normalized_weights


data = yf.download(tickers=asset_name, period='1y', interval='1d')
data
m_sb = (torch.DoubleTensor(generate_weights(data)))
m_sb = m.double()
m_sb 
sb.set_env(time_step=.1, pressure_slope=.01, heat_coefficient=.06)
best_vector, best_value = sb.maximize(m_sb, #domain='int10',
                                      agents=100, device='cuda',
                                      max_steps=10000, sampling_period=30, ballistic= True,
                                      convergence_threshold=50, use_window=True, heated=True, best_only=True)
```

I faced the following issue, any suggestions to solve this issue:

```
 Iterations       :   0%|          | 0/10000 [00:00<?, ? steps/s]
 Bifurcated agents:   0%|          | 0/100 [00:00<?, ? agents/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    109 
    110     def __compare_energies(self, sampled_spins: torch.Tensor) -> None:
--> 111         energies = torch.nn.functional.bilinear(
    112             sampled_spins.t(), sampled_spins.t(), torch.unsqueeze(self.ising_tensor, 0)
    113         ).reshape(self.n_agents)

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Double but found Float
```

...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: I can suggest debugging, stop at the error (set breakpoint or use auto-breakpoint at exception), go up the traceback to find the cause of the exception

Comment: Is that the full error?  With all traceback frames?  I'm guessing it's from the `sb.maximize` call.  That `sb` package that you import isn't included in your tags, and probably unknown to most SO readers.  You will have to dig into the `sb` documentation yourself.  This isn't the kind of error that a python/numpy programmrr can help with.    It looks like something compiled code would complain about.

Comment: This issue is solved by using the proposed instructions used [here](https://github.com/bqth29/simulated-bifurcation-algorithm/issues/46)